# Лишние срабатывания onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте.

**upd:**
Решение проблемы найдено. Решение в ответах.

Сначала немного кода, потом проблема:

HTML:

```
<div style="background:#ccc" onmouseover="over()">
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">another link</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function over() {
    alert('over');
}
```

Проблема в том, что событие `onmouseover` повторно срабатывает при наведении на любую из ссылок, даже если указатель мыши и до этого находился в границах `div`-a.

Вопрос в том, как обойти этот механизм. Мне нужно, чтобы событие вызывалось **только** в тот момент, когда пользователь наводит мышь на `div`.

Та же проблема наблюдается с `onmouseout`, но мне мнится, что решения у них должны быть аналогичными.

Кусок контекста для понимания проблемы:

Есть каскадное меню.

Подменюшки выплывают с помощью JS ибо клиента не устраивает их мгновенное появление при реализации через CSS.

Проблема в том, что процесс отрисовки подменю повторяется при наведении на его пункты.

Comment: только в тот момент, когда пользователь наводит мышь на div.

Ну и вешайте событие на div, сами же в вопросе дали ответ

Comment: событие и висит на `div`-e, но повторно срабатывает при наведении на ссылки в этом `div`-e содержащиеся.

С JS работаю не слишком плотно, по этому вероятно чего-то недопонимаю. Если так - поправьте меня пожалуйста.

Comment: Не вчитывался в вопрос когда писал комментарий.

В вашем случае нужно вешать обработчики непосредственно на ссылки, а не на div. Причина тому проста - div содержит в себе эти самые ссылки, соответственно наведение на любой дочерний элемент div'a порождает событие MouseOver для него самого.

Comment: @AlexWindHope В том то и проблема:

Мне нужно событие на диве, а не на ссылках =( т.е. события на ссылках меня не спасут.

Обработчик в процессе написания. Просто думал существует готовое решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

схематичное решение на случай если у кого-то будет подобный вопрос:

HTML:

```
<div style="background:#ccc" id="targeted_div">
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">another link</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('targeted_div');
    parent.onmouseover = parent.onmouseout = function(e) {
        e = e || event;
        if (!isOutside(e, this)) return;
        if(e.type == 'mouseout') {
            //действия при выходе
        } else {
            //действия при входе
        }
    }
}
```

модифицировал код взятый [отсюда](http://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-events#частота-событий-mousemove-и-mouseover)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="background:#ccc" onmouseover="over(event)">
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">another link</a>
</div>
<script>
function over(e){
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    e.target = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'div') return false;
    console.log(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase());
}
</script>
```

Проверка элемента довольно грубая. Хотя и привязка события такая же.

Comment: @ling спасибо. уже самостоятельно написал необходимый обработчик. все работает

Answer (score 0):

Очень вам рекомендую использовать для подобных проб, как у вас, выражение

```
console.log('сообщение в консоль');
```

Это уберет проблему лишнего нажатия на кнопку "ОК" алерта. Тем более, что может быть случай, когда что-то зациклится, и вы от алерта не избавитесь (только перегрузив страницу). Думаю, вы умеете пользоваться `JS`-консолью в браузере.
По поводу вашей проблемы. После того, как вы замените `alert()` на     `console.log('сообщение в консоль');`, проблема должна исчезнуть. Все дело, скорее, в том, что после активирования алерта и его деактивации, мышь как-бы снова попадает в поле зрения вашего дива. Вот оттуда и повторное срабатывание события.

Comment: console.log() - рулит, это да. только вот проблема несколько другая как мне показалось. Хотя формулировка вопроса не дает мне 100% уверенности.

Comment: А, нет, вы правы, событие навешивается еще на каждый внутренний элемент.

Comment: @Антон Мухин `alert` написан исключительно как пример действия функции.

код приведенный в вопросе - это просто схема, которую с кодом реальным роднит лишь общая проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте решить это дело, установив свойства position у ссылок в relative.
Есть еще один способ - удалять "прослушиватель" событий. Для этого используйте метод

> RemoveEventListener()

Comment: @Asen Это и породило мой вопрос.

Comment: @Asen Уже пробовал удалять события, но так как в конкретной задаче они парные (onmouseover/onmouseout), при отмене обработчика одного события автоматом создавался обработчик события обратного. Как следствие - тот же бардак

Я не указал это в вопросе в чем виноват.

btw задача решена